# fill column values based on row values from another dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I basically have this

```
   first    
0   bar 
1   bar 
2   foo 
3   foo
```

```
   bar foo
0   a   b
```

I want to insert value in dataframe 2 to dataframe 1, so the final result should be something like this

```
   first    
0   a   
1   a   
2   b   
3   b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use join on a transposed df2:

```
df1.set_index('first').join(df2.T)

Out[11]:
     0
bar  a
bar  a
foo  b
foo  b
```

Or with a dictionary:

```
df1['first'].map(df2.T.to_dict()[0])

Out[17]: 
0    a
1    a
2    b
3    b
Name: first, dtype: object
```

Or with merge:

```
df1.merge(df2.T.reset_index(), left_on=['first'], right_on=['index'])

  first index  0
0   bar   bar  a
1   bar   bar  a
2   foo   foo  b
3   foo   foo  b
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `replace` like so:

```
>>> df1.replace(df2.transpose()[0])
    first
0     a
1     a
2     b
3     b
```

If you want to check efficiency:

```
%timeit df1.replace(df2.transpose()[0])
711 µs ± 18.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: good answer, you propably could shorten it like this: `df1.replace(df2.T)[0])`